# How to create a category table that has SubCategories using EF Core Code-First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, code-first

I have created a simple table named "Category". Each category could have one or more subcategories or they could have no category.

I can't do it using EF core Code-First in ASP.NET 5. Would you mind help me to complete this table?

```
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Title {get;set;}
public int? parentId {get;set;}
```

How to set the relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want One to many relationships (Category to have many SubCategory).

Try this below code:-

```
public class Category{

public int Id { get; set; }
public string Title {get;set;}
public List<SubCategory> SubCategories{ get; set; }

}
```

```
public class SubCategory
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    //Navigation
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public Category Category{ get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
 public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int? ParentId { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Parent { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Category> Children { get; set; }

}
```

and db context

```
 public virtual DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
.....

 modelBuilder.Entity<Category>()
            .HasOne(s => s.Parent)
            .WithMany(m => m.Children)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.ParentId);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest setting up 2 tables (classes)

```
class Category {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
}
```

And then another one:

```
class SubCategory {
    public int Id {get;set;}

    public int CategoryId {get;set;}

    [ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryId))]
    public Category Category {get;set}

    public string SubCategoryTitle {get;set;}
}
```

More information under [Data Annotations in EF Core](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes)

Edit: This holds true, when at some point in time down the road the `Category` might have different fields than the `SubCategory`. If not, then a self-referencing table would be a nicer approach like Johnathan Barclay and Serge are suggesting.